# What has happened with opengl? What kind of nightmare is it now?

Tags: opengl

I used opengl 2 years ago. In one afternoon I read a tuto, I drew a cube (and then learned how to load any 3d model) and learned home to move the camera around with the mouse. It was easy, less than 100 lines of codes. I didnt get the pipeline completely but I was able to do *something*.

Now I need to refresh opengl for some basic stuff, basically I need to load a 3D model (any model) and move the model around, with the camera fixed. Something I thought would be another afternoon.

I have spent 1 day and have nothing working. I am reading the recommended tuto http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ I dont get anything, now to draw just a cube you need a lot of lines and working with lots of buffer, use some special syntax for shaders.... what the hell I only want to draw a cube. Before it was just defining 6 sides.

What is going on with opengl? Some would argue that now is great, I think it is screwed.
Is there any easy library to work with Something that would make my life easier?

Answer (score 8):

GLUT - http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/

ASSIMP - http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

These two libraries are all you need to make a simple application where you import a model (various formats). Read it's documentation and examples to get a better understanding on how you can "glue" OpenGL and ASSIMP to work.

[Documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_doc.html)

As to is OpenGL more hard to comprehend? No. What I've learned in recent years from OpenGL is that GFX programming is *never* simple or done in a few lines of code, you have to be organised, you have to be careful and even a simple primitive (e.g cube) needs to have more than 100 lines of code to make it decent and flexible (for example if you want more subdivisions on your polygons or texturing).

Answer (score 4):

If you learned it only  two years ago, then the tutorials were extremely outdated. Immediate Mode has been known to be deprecated for a very, very long time. Actually the first plans to abandon it and display lists date back to 2003.

Vertex Arrays have been around since version 1.1, and they have been the preferred method for sending geometry to OpenGL ever since; in immediate mode every vertex causes several function calls, so for any seriously complex object you spend more time managing the function call stack, than doing actual rendering work. If you used Vertex Arrays consequently since their introduction, switching over to Vertex Buffer Objects is as complicated as just inserting or replacing a few lines.

The biggest hurdle using OpenGL-3 is in Windows, where one has to use a proxy context to get access to the extension functions required to select OpenGL-3 capabilities for context creation. However again no big hurdle, 20 lines of code top. And some programs, like mine for example, create a proxy GL context anyway, to which all shareable data is uploaded, which allows to quicly destroy/recreate visible contexts, yet have full access to textures, VBOs and stuff (you can share VBOs, which is another reason for using them instead of plain vertex arrays; this might not look like something big, at least not if the context is used from a single process; however on plattforms like X11/GLX OpenGL contexts can be shared between X11 clients, which may even run on different machines!)

Also the existance of functions like the matrix manipulation stack led people into the misconception, OpenGL was some matrix math library, some even believed it was a particularily fast one. Neither is true. The removal of the matrix manipulation functions was a very important and right thing to do. Every serious OpenGL application will implement their very own matrix math anyway. For example any modern game using some kind of physics engine used to directly use in OpenGL (glLoadMatrix, or glUniformMatrix) the transform matrix spit out by the physics calculation, completely bypassing the rest of the matrix functions. This also means that the sole reason to have multiple matrix stacks (GL_PROJECTION, GL_MODELVIEW, GL_TEXTURE, GL_COLOR), namely being able to use the same set of manipulation functions on several matrices, was obsoleted and could have been replaced by something like `glLoadMatrixSelected{f,d}v(GLenum target, GLfloat *matrix)`. However Uniforms and shaders already were around, so the logical step was not introducing a new function, but to reuse existing API, which had been used for this task already, anway, and instead *remove* what's no longer needed.

TL;DR: The new OpenGL-3 API greatly simplyfies using it. It's a lot clearer, has fewer pitfalls and IMHO is also more newbie-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use buffer objects. You can use the deprecated immediate mode. It will be slower, but if you don't really care then go ahead and use OpenGL the way you used to. NeHe has some excellent [tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) on OpenGL 1.x stuff.

Swiftless has some good [tutorials](http://www.swiftless.com/opengltuts/opengl4tuts.html) (only a few very basic ones) on OpenGL 3.x and 4.x, but the learning curve is, as you've found, very steep.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be openGL? XNA offers an ability to draw 3d models without breaking your back.. Could be worth a look